# Chart.js: Sort the stacked bars by value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following stacked bar chart with the sample data. I want that per year (label) the individual stacked bars are sorted by the value. E.g. for 2019 the bar should be (form top to bottom) red (50), blue (20) and black (10).

https://jsfiddle.net/7rna08dm/2/

How can I achieve this? Is there the possibility to do this with the `datasets` property? Or is there any bar sorting property?

Currenctly I'm using the following data structure and didn't find a solution to achieve the expected behaviour with sorting the data:

```js
data: {
  labels: ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Max',
      data: [0, 0, 50, 10, 0, 70],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    {
      label: 'Peter',
      data: [10, 0, 20, 30, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dave',
      data: [0, 0, 10, 20, 0, 30],
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
  ],
},
```